# SVG height and width scaling not proportionally

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'm making a SVG and want it to scale not proportionally (or at least to have 4:3 and 16:9 variants in one file). I tried to picture how I want it to look - notice the border is changing, but shapes in the middle are the same. I'm working in the Inkscape on Linux OS.

What I mean, illustrated (couldn't embed images due to insufficient reputation):

[Original SVG](https://i.imgsafe.org/fe56dc142a.png)

[Border's width is changing, but rest of SVG stays intact](https://i.imgsafe.org/fe56f0bfa7.png)

I've looked through the options and internet, but couldn't find anything related. I'm not entirely sure what to look for. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Just to mention - I need border, which is also the SVG element, to change width and maintain height.

Answer (score 0):

Give the SVG a `viewBox` that matches the narrower aspect ratio.  It will automatically centre itself, as you want, when you make the view wider.

In the example below, the two SVGs are identical, they have just been assigned different `width` and `height`.

```css
/* 4x3 aspect ratio */
svg:nth-child(1) {
  width: 300px;
  height: 225px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

/* 16x9 aspect ratio */
svg:nth-child(2) {
  width: 400px;
  height: 225px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 120 90">
  <rect width="120" height="90" fill="lightgrey"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="300" r="240" fill="limegreen"/>
  <text x="60" y="50" text-anchor="middle">4 x 3</text>
</svg>

<svg viewBox="0 0 120 90">
  <rect width="120" height="90" fill="lightgrey"/>
  <circle cx="60" cy="300" r="240" fill="limegreen"/>
  <text x="60" y="50" text-anchor="middle">4 x 3</text>
</svg>
```

Comment: It's almost this - but will it work for the border too? Because that's my biggest issue. While elements should stay in place, border should follow the transforms.

Comment: I think you are going to have to describe what you want a bit better. I'm not sure I understand what you want any more. I thought you just wanted an SVG that stayed centred whether you viewed it at 4:3 or 16:9?